# Linux shell running programming simultaneuosly

Tags: linux

I need to run a programmme, let say ./a for 10 times in the linux shell. What is the command to do that?

Also, how could I differentiate the output from different processes?

Besides, my ./a is a continual process. How could I terminate it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Make a loop that starts the program 10 times in the background:

```
for i in $(seq 1 10) ; do
 ./a &
done
```

> Also, how could I differentiate the output from different processes?

You can't easily do that, the output can be interwined. Redirect the output of each process to a different file rather, e.g.

```
for i in $(seq 1 10) ; do
 ./a >output.$i  &
done
```

As a oneliner, you'd run

```
for i in $(seq 1 10) ; do ./a >output.$i  & done
```

to kill those processes later:

```
for i in $(seq 1 10) ; do kill %$i ; done
```

Comment: in bash, you can use {1..10} instead of calling external command

Answer (score 3):

In bash you can do:

```
for ((i=1;i<=10;i++)); do

  # run the command ./a and redirect its output to a file named after
  # its sequence number...like out1.txt, out2.txt...
  ./a > out$i.txt &   

done
```

The key here is the `&` which runs the command in the background. Without the `&` the 2nd `./a` will be started after the fist got completed, effectively making it serial execution. But with `&`, we don't wait for one invocation of `./a` to complete before we launch another one and that is how we achieve parallelism.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My ./a is a continual process. How could I terminate it? It seems like ctrl C does not terminate all the process

Comment: @Steven: when a command is ran with `&` at the end, the execution is detached and the process id (pid) is shown. To terminate it (or them), run `kill <pid>`.

Comment: If you want to be able to kill the processes on ctrl+c, then use the $! variable to obtain the pids, and then a subsequent loop with pgrep to watch them until they complete, and a trap with pkill in a loop to kill the individual processes.  Here's some useful links in case you need them: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-special-variables.htm

Comment: You can view all the background jobs in a shell with the `jobs` command. You can bring one of them to the foreground, by running `%4` , 4 is the job number here. You can kill that job by running `kill %4` . To make the current foreground job into a background job, hit CTRL+Z, and run `bg`  (that is, if you ran the loop posted here directly in the shell, not in a separate shell script)

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in {1..10}
do
  ./a > "out_${i}.txt" &
done
```

to terminate `a`, you can use `pkill a`

Comment: How is `pkill` different from a normal kill?

Comment: @gameover: it does exactly the same, but also accepts the process name as argument (or even a regex).

Comment: And by default `pkill` does a substring match on the process name, so literally using `pkill a` is likely to kill a lot of processes.

Comment: of course i am not with the idea of naming the program "a" to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use Bash or compatible shell, the special variable `$!` holds the process ID of the last process you made asynchronous. Augumenting nos' answer, I'd suggest using

```
for i in $(seq 1 10) ; do
    ./a 1> stdout.$i 2> stderr.$i &
    echo $! > pid.$i
done
```

Now you have error output in `stdout.X`, error output in `stderr.X` and the process ID in `pid.X` so you can kill it with

```
kill `cat pid.X`
```

or even kill all processes with

```
for i in $(seq 1 10) ; do
    kill `cat pid.$i`
done
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the other answers are fine so far, but you amy also want to try `repeat`, if supported by your system:

```
repeat 10 ./a
```

Here to differentiate outputs, unfortunately, you won't be able to use a counter variable. You can however use a timestamp:

```
repeat 10 ./a  >> output_`date +%N`
```

That being said, the behavior of `date` for anything below the second mark is unspecified, so that's not the most reliable way. A bit easier than to write a `for` loop though.